# Python socket always does the same

Tags: python, sockets

I wanted to make a program, with a server and a client(yes, still the same).
The client sends an request to the server, with an command.
And depending on the command the server sends an response.

Unfortunatly, regardless of the command, the client sends, the server always gives the same response, why?

Here is the server:

```
import socket
import errno
import pickle

def Main():
    host = '192.168.178.151'
    port = 12345


    all_text = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
    music_text = ['Konzert1', 'Konzert2', 'Konzert3']

    all_description = ['Test \n Description1\n', 'Test \n Description1\n', 'Test \n Description1\n']

    all_images = ['http://192.168.178.151/unlock.png', 'http://192.168.178.151/unlock.png', 'http://192.168.178.151/unlock.png']
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(1)


    while True:

        c, addr = s.accept()
        c.setblocking(0)

        print "Connection from: " + str(addr)

        try:
            pcommand = c.recv(2048)
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                pass

        command = pickle.loads(pcommand)

        print command[0]
        if command[0] == 'GIVEALL':

            textstring = pickle.dumps([all_text, all_images, all_description])#verwandelt Liste in String
            c.send(textstring)

        elif command[0] == 'GIVEMUSIC':
            textstring = pickle.dumps([music_text, all_images, all_description])#verwandelt Liste in String
            c.send(textstring)

        elif command[0] == 'ADD':

            caption = command[1]
            image = command[2]
            describtion = command[3]
            city = command[4]


        try:
            c.close()

            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        except socket.error as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
                raise
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

And here is the Client:

```
import socket
import pickle

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class Netclient(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.texte = []
        self.city = 'Pawonkuw'
        self.ip = '192.168.178.151'
        self.port = 12345

    def giveWid(self, current='All'):

        if current == 'All':
            self.texte, self.images, self.description = self.sentHOT(self.ip, self.port)
        elif current == 'Music':
            self.texte, self.images, self.description = self.sentMusic(self.ip, self.port)

        return self.texte, self.images, self.description

    def sentHOT(self, host, port):

        self.s = socket.socket()

        self.s.connect((host, port))
        command = ['GIVEALL', self.city]
        pcommand = pickle.dumps(command)
        self.s.send(pcommand)#sends command

        recived_string = self.s.recv(1023)

        more_text = pickle.loads(recived_string)#verwandelt string in liste

        self.s.close()

        return more_text[0], more_text[1], more_text[2]

    def sentMusic(self, host, port):
        self.s = socket.socket()

        self.s.connect((host, port))
        command = ['GIVEMUSIC', self.city]
        pcommand = pickle.dumps(command)
        self.s.send(pcommand)#sends command

        recived_string = self.s.recv(1023)

        more_text = pickle.loads(recived_string)#verwandelt string in liste

        self.s.close()

        self.images = ['unlock.png', 'unlock.png', 'unlock.png']

        return more_text[0], more_text[1], more_text[2]

    def add_event(self, caption, image, description, city='Pawonkow'):
        #print 'Add event executed'
        self.s = socket.socket()

        self.s.connect((self.ip, self.port))

        new_event = ['ADD', caption, image, description, self.city]
        new_compact_event = pickle.dumps(new_event)
        self.s.send(new_compact_event)


        self.s.close()


n = Netclient()
t, i, d = n.giveWid()
print t
t, i, d = n.giveWid(current='Music')
print t
n.add_event('new', 'new.png', 'ew event', 'Hanau')
```

Comment: You should try cutting this example down a bit. It would make it easier to see the real problem.

Comment: What is the response from the server?

Comment: what does `print command[0]` evaluate as when it outputs to your server?

Comment: `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)` should be before `s.bind()`. Try setting `pcommand = False` after `pickle.loads` so there is no chance that it is set during the next iteration if `c.recv()` fails.

Comment: OK, I am sorry, the Problem was, that if the error is handeled, no command is send

Answer (score 0):

Your server code should handle the possibility that `c.recv()` fails,

```
while True:
    try:
        pcommand = c.recv(2048)
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK or e.errno == errno.EAGAIN:
            continue
        else:
            pass # raise an error / handle in some other way
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this Problem, but I don't like it, because it uses to much internet volume.
The Problem was that the error was handeled by the try... except clause, but if an error occured, it was handeled and than nothing happened, so pcommand stayed the same.
So I made a recursive funktion, that tries to connect untill the connection works.

Does anyoneknows a Solution that uses less resources????
please help

```
def get_com(c):
    try:
        pcommand = c.recv(2048)
        print pcommand
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK or e.errno == errno.EAGAIN:
            print 'error: rev doesnt work'
            pcommand = get_com(c)
    return pcommand
```

.....

```
pcommand = get_com(c)

command = pickle.loads(pcommand)
```